# Mongo Node.js Driver upsertedCount not being set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, driver

I'm upserting documents into Mongo using the native Node.js driver.

I need to detect whether the document is upserted or not. The upsertedCount property returned by the driver in the result seems like a good choice for this.

This property does not get set, however. upsertedCount remains 0 even when new document is inserted into the collection. upsertedId is also null.

```
var update_res = await col.updateOne({name: 'bla}}, {$setOnInsert: obj}, {upsert: true});
console.log(update_res);
```

Result:

```
modifiedCount: undefined,
upsertedId: null,
upsertedCount: 0,
matchedCount: undefined
```

The result property only contains an "ok" property (no "nModified" or "n" properties):

```
result: { ok: 1 }
```

MongoDB Node.js native driver, version 3.1.0

MongoDB version 4.0.2

Comment: This doesn't seem like the intended solution, but what's worked for me is using `col.findOneAndUpdate` with `{ upsert: true }` and the answer is in `result.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting`. It feels like a hack though...

Comment: Thank you so much! This does indeed work. But yeah it does feel like a hack. I'll let you know if I find a less hacky solution.